# What do the fake advertisements in WandaVision mean?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, wandavision

Most of the episodes of *WandaVision* have a "commercial break" (like a real TV show would), complete with a fake advertisement that seem to have a deeper meaning to them. For example, there's one that talks about Strucker, which is likely a reference to his experiments with the Mind Stone on Wanda.

What are all the advertisements and what do they mean?

Answer (score 30):

#### Episode 1, "Filmed Before a Live Studio Audience"

This is the Toast Mate advert, the Toast Mate is made by Stark Industries. When it's working the light on the front flashes faster and faster with a corresponding beep. This is certainly a reference to the Stark bomb that was defective that hit their home but never went off.

> **Pietro Maximoff:** We were ten years old, having dinner, the four of us. When the first shell hits, two floors below, it makes a hole in the floor. It's big. Our parents go in, and the whole building starts coming apart. I grab her, roll under the bed and the second shell hits. But, it doesn't go off. It just...sits there in the rubble, three feet from our faces. And on the side of the shell is painted one word...
>
> **Wanda Maximoff:** Stark.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Age of Ultron*</sub>

[image: The Toast Mate 2000 advert]

Of course we see this bomb in Episode 8 as well as Agatha is escorting Wanda through key moments in her journey to become who she is now. And the Toast Mate's light also [blips red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W3gJ.png), further mimicking the bomb.

[image: The Stark bomb embedded in the ruined building]

#### Episode 2, "Don't Touch That Dial"

This is the Strücker watch. Clearly Strücker is the man who performed the experiments on Wanda with the Mind Stone on behalf of Hydra and it also has the Hydra name and symbol on it. This just seems to be referencing these experiments and where Wanda's powers came from. I can't see anything else to it.

[image: Strucker watch advert]

#### Episode 3, "Now in Color"

This is the Hydra Soak advert. There seems to be more to this than I can think of because the advert contains obvious references to Hydra: the name and the packaging is covered with octopi in the style of Hydra's symbol. However, I'm not too sure on what that reference means in relation to the rest of the advert.

The rest of the advert is clearly telling us how Wanda created the hex to escape from her own reality. She *"needs a break"* and she has escaped to a world all of her own.

> **Commercial Narrator:** Escape to a world all your own, where your problems float away. When you wanna get away, but you don't wanna go anywhere...
>
> <sub>*WandaVision*, Season 1 Episode 3, "Now in Color"</sub>

[image: Hydra Soak advert]

#### Episode 5, "On a Very Special Episode..."

This is the Lagos paper towels advert. This one is a clear reference to the events of *Captain America: Civil War*. In the film we see Wanda in Lagos accidentally divert a blast away from one group to another leading to lost lives and eventually the Sokovia Accords. The tagline for the product is *"For when you make a mess you didn't mean to."*

I've seen it mentioned that this could also have a second meaning in relation to men stepping in: whether that's Vision becoming more aware in the hex, Vision having to "guard" her at the Avengers compound or Stark and the UN stepping in to create the Sokovia Accords. This is because it's the first advert where the man is doing cleaning up and there's also the line *"Husbands can use it too, you know."*

[image: Lagos logo for the advert]

#### Episode 6, "All-New Halloween Spooktacular!"

This is the Yo-Magic! yoghurt advert. This is the first one to reference something that hasn't happened yet but hints at the future. It wasn't clear at the time but it was revealed at the start of episode 8 that Agatha is a witch who can absorb magic. This is hinting at her motivations to come to the hex to absorb the magic... especially once she knew Wanda was the Scarlet Witch.

> **Shark:** Snacked on Yo-Magic, bro! Now I have time to hang fin.
>
> <sub>*WandaVision*, Season 1 Episode 6, "All-New Halloween Spooktacular!"</sub>

[image: The shark holds up the Yo-Magic! yoghurt pots.]

#### Episode 7, "Breaking the Fourth Wall"

Lastly, we have the Nexus pills advert. There's a lot to unpack with this advert. If we take it at face value it just seems to be relating to Wanda's creation of the hex and that she needs to move on, deal with her feelings and end what is happening here.

> **Narrator:** Feeling depressed? Like the world goes on without you? Do you just want to be left alone? Ask your doctor about Nexus. A unique anti-depressant that works to anchor you back to your reality. Or the reality of your choice. Side effects include feeling your feelings, confronting your truth, seizing your destiny, and possibly, more depression. You should not take Nexus unless your doctor has cleared you to move on with your life. Nexus, because the world doesn't revolve around you. Or does it?
>
> <sub>*WandaVision*, Season 1 Episode 7, "Breaking the Fourth Wall"</sub>

However, it may mean more than that and could tie into *Doctor Strange and the Multiverse of Madness*. The use of reality could either be the more mundane mention above (leave the hex and return to "normal" life) or could be referring to their universe and their own reality. If that is the case it will certainly play into DS2, especially with the product being called Nexus. However, we will have to wait on that to see.

[image: The Nexus pills advert]

Comment: Nexus was also the name of the Internet facility that Vision was interfacing with in AoU.

Comment: @Valorum I can't think of how that would tie in to the advert but good spot, no way would I remember that name!

Comment: In the comics, there is also the "The Nexus of all realities" A magical place where all realities meet and you can travel to any of them if you have the magic to pull it off. It could be a spoiler for a plot point in the upcoming Dr Strange movie. It was also the place that brought Howard the Duck to the Marvel Earth, so maybe we will see him again too.

Comment: @BjornEriksson Aye, I didn't want to elaborate too much on any possible DS2 theories so left it relatively open ended. We've also seen Howard the Duck twice so far, at least.

Comment: It's worth noting that the toaster in the commercial in Episode 1 had a strange red light on it. It stood out because it actually was red in an otherwise black-and-white episode

Comment: @Machavity I read that but when I watched the ad back on YouTube it just looked B&W still. I'll have to watch again on Disney+ to double check,

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Yeah, I went looking and both YouTube and the D+ Twitter have a B&W light. Since I thought I was going crazy, I fired up D+ and the version they have clearly shows a red light flashing during the long awkward pause (happens around 10:29)

Comment: Maybe it is worth mentioning that this could very well be an unconscious road through the becoming of (Wanda's) reality. That makes the **goddess* part more sensible as well: As it is about her becoming self-conscious as the creator (and goddess) of this reality by going through her history and flashes of parts of her consciousness registering aspects of the hex (and thus herself)

Comment: The tagline on the Toast Mate is also significant: *"Forget the past, this is your future!"*.  Definitely seems appropriate to Wanda's mental state...

Comment: "Hydra-Soak: Find the goddess within" could refer to Hydra helping Wanda unlock her God-like powers.

Comment: Phil Coulson also made mention of Hydra tampering with soap in order to control people's minds. Could be a real deep cut but maybe one nonetheless.

Comment: In the comics Wanda is referred to as a Nexus being, someone who exists in all versions of reality with the same name and powers.

Comment: In episode 6 (the shark/yoghurt ad) the boy dies trying to break the seal of the food. In the same episode, Vision almost dies trying to break through the seal of the hex

Comment: Huh. I have not watched the show, so barely comprehend question or answers here, **but** the still you provide from the in-world toaster commercial reminds me very much of [*Stray Toasters*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stray_Toasters) (written and illustrated by Bill Sienkiewicz of amazing mid-80s New Mutants fame :). I wonder if the *WandaVision* writers are making a nod to Bill's little four-shot?

Comment: There could be more to the meaning of NExux now, with Loki Nexus events...

Comment: @MaurizioIndenmark There's certainly more to it now, I think it's more likely to play out in DS2 though so I'll probably leave the answer as it stands just for now.

Answer (score 5):

Possibly a last-minute change (no other version of the video I can find has this) was the colorizing of the Toast Mate 2000 light in the Episode 1 commercial. This ties it better to the flashing red light on the Stark bomb. It also better ties into this Episode 8 reveal from later in the episode

> The awkward pause for the beeping is important because we see that the stress it creates helps Wanda cast her first spell: a probability hex (according to Agatha) that makes the bomb not explode

[image: It's a beeping... toaster?]

Comment: Have you got evidence that it was a last minute change?

Comment: Yeah, I reworded it. It's weird that the videos differ from D+ on this

Comment: "It's weird that the videos differ from D+ on this" — Wanda! Stop messing with reality!

Answer (score 1):

The first four ads correlate pretty closely to the four time periods that Wanda and Agnes revisit in Ep. 8. so they're possibly the repressed pain that the townsfolk had to endure in the form of a commercial break:

- Stark Toaster -> Under the table waiting for stark bomb to explode
- Strucker Watch -> Hydra Facility being observed and exploited
- Hydra Soak -> Chillin' with Vision at Avengers Tower
- Lagos Towels -> Breaking into S.W.O.R.D. and creating the whole Westview mess

the last two commercials may be when Agatha started to directly influence things, at some point she started to mess with Wanda directly and not just indirectly since she was there in "The Office" interviewers seat.  They concerned Agatha's motivations and intentions for Wanda.

---

The timing of the ads within the show also were very unnatural *Deus ex Machina* methods of getting out of a jamb for the story.  So that might have something to do with it as well.

Comment: She never broke into SWORD, that was Hayward framing her.

Comment: @the well she magic'ed a door and a window.